# How to call a function from a route in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, url-routing

I'm developing an AngularJS project and I was wondering if it's possible to create a route that just calls a function, and then redirects.

I want to use this for having a `/logout` route that calls the logout() function on the authentication and authorization service and then redirects to `/login`.

A stripped version of my route configuration:

```
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '/app/login/login.html',
    controller: 'login'
})
.when('/logout', {
    redirectTo: '/login'
})
```

But obviously this doesn't actually logout the user (and because the user is still authorized the user is again returned to the root by the authorization service).

What would be a good solution to this? (The simplest solution being directly calling it from the menu, but this feels like a dirty hack that uses global scope.)

Comment: you could add a route parameter to /login, like /login/:logout then have /logout redirect to /login/1 and in your login controller check the $routeParams.logout to see if it should log you out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. 
As an alternative could you simply attach ng-click with logout() invocation and then redirect back to /login screen?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, but I'm looking for an approach that doesn't involve just calling a global function.

Answer (score 0):

Run the function with `ngInit`

```
<div ng-init="runMe()"></div>
```

call the function which is inside the controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.initialize = function () {
        alert("Kingdom");
    }
});
```

Comment: Like I stated on the other answer way over a year ago, I wasn't looking for calling some global function. I ended up going for the approach that the directive and service I'm using for the menu binds a handler to the button. So I no longer use a route for it.